# Flutter - Replace a subsstring with a Widget

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I am building an application with flutter, but I am having a bit of trouble with one of my widgets. I am getting a JSON response from an API endpoint in order to build the comments on posts, but I need to be able to take part of a string and wrap it in a `GestureDetector`, in order to handle "@ mentions".

For example: I have the string `hey there @MattChris how are you?` I need to be able to wrap the `@MattChris` in a `GestureDetector`.

At the moment I parse the incoming string and provide a list with each space-separated word from the actual comment. Like so:

```
List<Widget> comment = new List();

outer: for (String word in json['content'].toString().split(" ")) {
  if (word != null && word.isNotEmpty) {
    if (word.startsWith('@')) {

      comment.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: goToProfile,
        child: Text(word + ' ')
      );

    } else {
      comment.add(Text(word + ' '));
    }
  }
}
```

Only issue now is that's a lot of extra elements taking up memory, and a difficulty with ensuring that the text wraps in the way I expect. I've seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619419/how-to-make-a-piece-of-text-dynamically-received-from-json-clickable-in-flutter), but I'm not sure how to ensure that text wraps as if it were one string in a `Text` widget.

Comment: check `Text.rich` / `RichText`

Comment: in the link you posted they use `Text.rich` too, so whats the problem actually?

Comment: The problem with the implementation that I linked is I can have multiple items that would need to be replaced within a single string. The comments mentioned a loop in children, but I don't think I quite get it.

Comment: `RichText` will wrap your text as if it are in a single Text widget!

Comment: `child: Builder(
 builder: (context) {
 List<InlineSpan> children = [];
 var pattern = RegExp('@[a-z]*');
 'ask @john or @mary ...'.splitMapJoin(pattern, 
 onMatch: (Match match) {
 var recognizer = MultiTapGestureRecognizer();
 recognizer.onTap = (i) { print('${match[0]} clicked !!!'); };
        
   children.add(TextSpan(text: match[0], recognizer: recognizer, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)));
  },
  onNonMatch: (String text) {
  children.add(TextSpan(text: text));
  },
 );
 return Text.rich(TextSpan(children: children, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)));
 }
),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to come to a working solution. Reading from the implementation I liked to again, and looking in the comments, I decided to use a recursive function:

```
List<TextSpan> _mentionParser(String message, Iterable<dynamic> mentions) {
  if (message == null || message.isEmpty) // Don't return anything if there is no message.
    return [];

  for (Map<String, dynamic> mention in mentions) { // Loop through the list of names to replace
    if (message.contains("@${mention['username']}")) { // If the message contains the name to replace
      List<TextSpan> _children = [];
      String preUsernameMessage = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("@${mention['username']}")).trimLeft(); // Get everything before the mention
      if (preUsernameMessage != null && preUsernameMessage.isNotEmpty)
        _children.add(TextSpan(children: _mentionParser(preUsernameMessage, mentions))); // if it isn't empty, recurse and add to the list

      _children.add( // Always add the display name to the list
        TextSpan(
          text: "${mention['display_name']}".trim(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff2e6da4)),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () => {gotoProfile(json['username'])}
        )
      );

      String postUsernameMessage = message.substring(message.indexOf("@${mention['username']}") + "@${mention['username']}".length, message.length).trimRight(); // Get everything after the mention
      if (postUsernameMessage != null && postUsernameMessage.isNotEmpty) // If it isn't empty, recurse and add it to the list
        _children.add(TextSpan(children: _mentionParser(postUsernameMessage, mentions)));

      return _children; // return the constructed list
    }
  }
  return [TextSpan(text: message)]; // If the string didn't contain any of the strings to replace, then just return the message as passed.
}
```

Then I just call this as the `children` variable on a `TextSpan` inside `Text.rich`. It took some time, but I was able to get the implementation working!

Comment: thanks for sharing this
just what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
public String method(String str) {
if (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'x') {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
return str; // to remove last character
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.